# Argument passed to Shopify\Utils::loadCurrentSession() must be of the type array

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, shopify-api

I am trying to connect to [Shopify Rest Admin API](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest) using PHP and I am using [Shopify API's PHP library](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-php) and I initialize successfully like this:

```
Shopify\Context::initialize(
    'key',
    'secret',
    'scope_1, scope_2',
    'https://example.com',
    new FileSessionStorage('/tmp/php_sessions'),
    '2022-10',
);
```

But when I try to make a request like this:

```
$this->test_session = Utils::loadCurrentSession(
    $requestHeaders,
    $requestCookies,
    $isOnline
);
Webhookv2::webhooks(
    $this->test_session, // Session
    [], // Url Ids
    [], // Params
);
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Shopify\Utils::loadCurrentSession() must be of the type array, null given, called in /www/doc/www.example.com/www/script/index.php on line 45 and defined in /www/doc/www.example.com/www/script/vendor/shopify/shopify-api/src/Utils.php:158 Stack trace: #0 /www/doc/www.example.com/www/script/index.php(45): Shopify\Utils::loadCurrentSession(NULL, NULL, NULL) #1 {main} thrown in /www/doc/www.example.com/www/script/vendor/shopify/shopify-api/src/Utils.php on line 158
```

What am I missing?

P.S.
The code in the Utils.php file (part of Shopify PHP library) that corresponds to the three session variables above:

```
/**
 * Loads the current user's session based on the given headers and cookies.
 *
 * @param array $rawHeaders The headers from the HTTP request
 * @param array $cookies    The cookies from the HTTP request
 * @param bool  $isOnline   Whether to load online or offline sessions
 *
 * @return Session|null The session or null if the session can't be found
 * @throws \Shopify\Exception\CookieNotFoundException
 * @throws \Shopify\Exception\MissingArgumentException
 */
public static function loadCurrentSession(array $rawHeaders, array $cookies, bool $isOnline): ?Session
{
    $sessionId = OAuth::getCurrentSessionId($rawHeaders, $cookies, $isOnline);

    return Context::$SESSION_STORAGE->loadSession($sessionId);
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear - it says your `$requestHeaders` is `null`, and shouldn't be.  So how are you setting that variable?

Answer (score 0):

The `loadCurrentSession` method requires `$requestHeaders` to be an array ([docs](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-php/blob/main/docs/usage/utils.md#loadCurrentSession)).
Make sure the `$requestHeaders` variable you pass as argument is indeed an array. Something like:

```
$requestHeaders = array( 
                     'api_version' => '2023-01', 
                     'X-Shopify-Access-Token' => 'ACCESS_TOKEN'
                  );
$requestCookies = array();
$isOnline = true;

$this->test_session = Utils::loadCurrentSession(
    $requestHeaders,
    $requestCookies,
    $isOnline
);
```